# Total Of Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Ok so, I have a form at the moment which lets uers select certain radio buttons but if certain radio buttons are selectd then others cannot.

I have set up a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_KP/BwmzQ/) so you can see this a lot easier. I know the code may look a bit messey.

The problem I am having is at the bottom of the form there is a section `Order Total (excluding VAT):` which adds up the total of the radio buttons. The problem is for example if you check the radio button at the top left  (£25 Year 1 All Blocks & Units (15 assessments in total) ) Then at the section `Order Total (excluding VAT):` it shows £25 in the Total Box. Then if you check the radio button below that is £47.50 the total box says £47.50 which is all fine. But then say the user changes there mind and goes back the the £25 option it keeps the £47.50 and adds the £25 on top so it says £72.50 when it should just be £25. You can see the prices for the radio buttons are set by `data-price="25"`

So my question having a look through the code is it possbile for the total to only add up the radio buttons that are checked?

I think it is to do with it caching what has been previouslly selectd and to do with this code?

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    var total = 0.0;
    $('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    });
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: I understand that user can select only one option for each "Key Stage", so you can do that by setting all name of radio buttons as  same for each key stage. and for controlling which option selected, add a new attribute instead of using name attribute.

Comment: @ocanal That part is working it is the totaling of the radio buttons. It is caching them I think so when a new one is selected it adds it on it only needs to add the radio buttons which are selected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of execution order.

You have three sets of event handlers put in place with jQuery.on(), jQuery.click() and jQuery.change(). I would not like to guess which order these events fire and it's quite probable that the order differs from browser to browser.

Consequently, the summation handler can run before the other handlers and that's what appears to be happening.

To be safe I would write one unique handler for all radio buttons. Branch internally to respond to particular cases, then finally run the summation loop.

Comment: Im not the best with jQuery is it possible for you to help me out?